# How to combine click and taphold into single call

Tags: jquery, events, touch, touch-event

I have a problem in that the JQuery click event handler is not triggered for a long touch press (Chromium browser kiosk application on a Raspberry Pi4 with a touch screen). It can be the case that older/slower people can touch buttons etc. very slowly, and in this case the click event is not triggered. I want that the click event is triggered in this case. I could use touchstart, touchmove and touchend events instead of the click event, but that would mean 3 event handlers for each UI element, and each with their own touchdown flags as they shouldn't be able to interfere with other UI element's flag state.

I can't think of an easy way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the desired behaviour with the following code

```
// removes context menu event that was interfering with long key presses
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
})

// do click event from long key press
window.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(e.target).trigger("click");
})
```